# How to get MATLAB to show error message in workspace when executing GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, debugging, runtime-error

I have created a GUI programmatically (i.e. without using GUIDE) in MATLAB Online (matlab.mathworks.com instead of using the software itself).

I am experiencing a problem in the execution of one of the push button functions (i have programmed the callback but it does not work). However, when the GUI figure is active, MATLAB does not throw out an error in the command window like it usually does when executing normal scripts when it reaches a point in the program where there is an error in the coding. Because of this issue, I have had to guess my problem and debug via trial and error until the function works. It has been fine so far but I have finally reached an issue which I am really not sure what the problem is.

Is there a way to make MATLAB online throw out the error to the command window so I am able to troubleshoot and debug my program?

Thanks.

Comment: I have not done any GUI programming since matlab 2013b, but I think that the errors showed up in the command window at least when I did it. However, I have never got errors to show up in workspace. Maybe you meant exception?

Comment: these errors refer to when you are in the execution of the gui? I only get the errors showing up in the command window when i am compiling the program, but not when I am "playing" with the GUI buttons.

Comment: Did you try debugging with MATLAB (with breakpoints, step-by-step execution etc.?

Comment: You can view the last error that occurred with the `lasterr` command, maybe this helps

Comment: An option would be to put the callback code into `try` - `catch` blocks and either output the error manually, or set a breakpoint in the `catch` block for debugging.

Comment: @mtigger It is also possible to catch the exception in the try-catch block. This would then display the full stack trace until to the level where you have the try-catch block `try, %do something; catch err, disp(err); end`. You do not need to define `err` create a custom exception class or so. Just type exactly what I wrote around the code you want to execute (which will replace the do something comment of course). However, you may want to edit the `disp`. That one is there mostly to show you what you get.

Comment: I realise that this issue of no runtime error feedback in the command window is only on MATLAB online which i was using. when i copied the file over to the MATLAB software itself the problem was solved with the errors shown in the command window. Unfortunately, I am unable to edit the tag in this question to show matlab-online instead of just matlab as that tag is not yet created. Thanks everyone for their answers.